# addEventListener click doesn't working when I dynamically changing buttons

Tags: javascript, button, click, addeventlistener

I have 3 inputs: for name, last name and education. The last input (for education) might be multiple so I have button to add more inputs. This process work dynamically but it has one flaw. The addEventListener method works only for the very first static button but not for buttons created in the process.  In my opinion addEventListener couldn't catch updated ID for the element and work for the previous element only... Any ideas?

```
let counter = 0;
let buttonName, additionalId, additionalEducation, buttonId, dynamicButton, buttonIdListener, counter1;
additionalId = "education" + counter;
additionalEducation = "Education " + counter;
buttonId = "add"+counter;
buttonName = "name"+counter;


document.getElementById(buttonId).addEventListener('click', function(){

    // let hide = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    // hide.style.display = 'none';
    counter= counter+1;

    additionalId = "education" + counter;
    additionalEducation = "Education " + counter;
    buttonId = "add"+counter;
    buttonName = "name"+counter;

    let additionalLabel = document.createElement('label');
    additionalLabel.innerHTML = additionalEducation;
    additionalLabel.setAttribute('for',additionalId);

    let additionalInput = document.createElement('input');
    additionalInput.setAttribute('id',additionalId);
    additionalInput.style.borderRadius = "5px";
    additionalInput.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    additionalInput.style.color = "white";

    let additionalButton = document.createElement('button');
    additionalButton.setAttribute('type','button');
    additionalButton.setAttribute('id',buttonId);
    additionalButton.setAttribute('name',buttonName);
    additionalButton.innerHTML = "Add";

    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(additionalLabel);
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(additionalInput);
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(additionalButton);


})
```

and its my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <label for="name0">სახელი</label>
        <input type="text" id="name0" name="name">
        <label for="last_name0">გვარი</label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name0" name="last_name">
        <div>
            <label for="education0">განათლება</label>
            <input type="text" id="education0" name="education">
            <button type="submit" id="add0">დამატება</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your listener on a static object - one that won't be removed or added. So you can use 'form' and set it like this:

First, update your static html button with a class - for this example 'the-button'

```
<button type="submit" class='the-button' id="add0">დამატება</button>
```

Then setup your event listener. Im going wrap this in a window.onload function to make sure it doesn't run until the HTML has rendered.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("form").addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
   if (evt.target.classList.contains('the-button')) theFunction(evt.target);
  });
}
```

Then we stick your logic into a function, making sure to add the class `the-button` to any newly created buttons so they can pick up the listener.

```
function theFunction(fromButton) {
    // fromButton is just in case you want a reference from the button that was clicked
    counter= counter+1;

    additionalId = "education" + counter;
    additionalEducation = "Education " + counter;
    buttonId = "add"+counter;
    buttonName = "name"+counter;

    let additionalLabel = document.createElement('label');
    additionalLabel.innerHTML = additionalEducation;
    additionalLabel.setAttribute('for',additionalId);

    let additionalInput = document.createElement('input');
    additionalInput.setAttribute('id',additionalId);
    additionalInput.style.borderRadius = "5px";
    additionalInput.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    additionalInput.style.color = "white";

    let additionalButton = document.createElement('button');
    additionalButton.setAttribute('type','button');
    additionalButton.setAttribute('id',buttonId);
    additionalButton.classList.add('the-button');
    additionalButton.setAttribute('name',buttonName);
    additionalButton.innerHTML = "Add";

    
document.getElementById("form").appendChild(additionalLabel);
        document.getElementById("form").appendChild(additionalInput);
        document.getElementById("form").appendChild(additionalButton);
}
```

Comment: @ZakooKoo - fantastic! Please accept as the answer by clicking the checkmark. Cheers